# How to reschedule activities after entering actuals in MS Project 2010

Tags: ms-project, tracking, ms-project-2010

Like in MS Project 2007, there was a button “reschedule”. We clicked it after entering actuals on activities. The “reschedule” button calculates activity’s remaining duration and changes it accordingly.

I dont see this button in MS Project 2010. How do we reschedule activities after entering actuals?

Answer (score 1):

On the Project tab, under status date, there is an "update project" button.  Is this what you mean?